# How to make python work with c# methods with optional params

Tags: c#, python, reflection, optional-parameters, python.net

I am working on a project where the applications use python and PyQt for front-end, and the backend is written in C#. I defined a method in C#:

```
public void methodA(int param1, int param2=0,int param3=5){
    // some code
}
```

But when calling it from Python using pythonnet (Python for .NET):

```
methodA(param1)
```

I get the error message: **"No method matches given arguments"**. I understand that it has to do somehow with reflection.

My question is:
**1.** Is there any other way except: calling the method( in Python) like this: `methodA(param1,0,5)` 
                                      or using reflection
**2.** If not, what needs to be done to enable this to work via reflection.

**EDIT:** the difference between the questions is that I can pass the values for my optional parameters, and the function call will work, but if I try to call methodA with one parameter it will not. This is the first failing example in the linked question. The reason why I don't want to pass the default value for the parameters all the time is because we have over 300 calls to that function.

Comment: There are few solutions listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742837/creating-a-c-sharp-nullable-int32-within-python-using-python-net-to-call-a-c-s