# Automating Microsoft word with Python.Net

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

How to automate Microsoft office using office interop with python.net?
I tried following but gives error:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop")

from Microsoft.Office.Interop import Word

wordApp = Word.Application()
wordApp.Visible = True
doc1 = wordApp.Documents.Add()
```

> AttributeError: '__ComObject' object has no attribute 'Add'

Comment: In an old C# project, I have `Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);`.  The four parameters became optional in C# 4.0, around 2010, which was meant to make COM calls much easier, e.g. `Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add();`, but this feature may not yet be supported in Python.NET.  Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742837/creating-a-c-sharp-nullable-int32-within-python-using-python-net-to-call-a-c-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple wrapper that enables COM interop with pythonnet. Full details here:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/260

Comment: Is `class comobj(object):` what you refer as wrapper?

Comment: Exactly, but it is very basic